# $(12) \notin \langle (132), (123456) \rangle$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

How can I prove/disprove that as an element of $S_6, $ $(12) \notin \langle (132), (123456) \rangle$. We can use GAP to check this, but by hand it looks not so obvious.

Let $r=(123456)$ is odd and $s=(132)$ is even , so any word in {$r^{\pm},{s^{\pm}}$}, can give an odd permutation as well as even.

Comment: Did you try it in GAP?

Comment: I am downloading it. But my friend posed this problem...

Comment: @DerekHolt The second sentence of the question is: "We can use GAP to check this, but by hand it looks not so obvious."

Comment: @A.P. Yes, but I am querying the accuracy of that statement!

Comment: Try proving instead that $(1,2) \not\in \langle (1,3,5),(1,2,3,4,5,6) \rangle$ (which is true).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By hand:
$$(1\ 2)=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)^4(1\ 3\ 2)(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)^4(1\ 3\ 2)(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)^5$$

This is how I worked it out:
$$(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)=(1\ 2)(2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)$$
so
$$(1\ 2)=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)(2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)^{-1}=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)[(2\ 3\ 4)(4\ 5\ 6)]^{-1}$$
and of course
$$(2\ 3\ 4)=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)(1\ 2\ 3)(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)^{-1}=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)(1\ 3\ 2)^{-1}(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)^{-1}$$
and
$$(4\ 5\ 6)=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)^3(1\ 2\ 3)(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)^{-3}=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)^3(1\ 3\ 2)^{-1}(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)^{-3}$$
etc.

Comment: how you worked that out?

Answer (score 8):

GAP tells me this:

```
gap> G := Group((1,3,2), (1,2,3,4,5,6));
Group([ (1,3,2), (1,2,3,4,5,6) ])
gap> (1,2) in G;
true
gap> GeneratorsOfGroup(G);
[ (1,3,2), (1,2,3,4,5,6) ]
gap> Factorization(G, (1,2));
(x2^2*x1^-1)^2*x2
```

Comment: ohh..  This was unexpected. He asked me a wrong question. Damn

Answer (score 1):

$(1\,3\,2)$ means that you can do a *cyclic* permutation of any three neighbors in the long cycle, by conjugating with an appropriate multiple of $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6)$.

In particular you can move one element *two* places to the left or to the right in the cyclic order. Since there is an odd number of *other* elements to jump over, moving one element all the way around the large cycle in steps of two will leave it swapped with its neighbor.

Thus, we can make $({}^1_2 {\,}^2_3 {\,}^3_1 {\,}^4_4 {\,}^5_5 {\,}^6_6) = (1\,3\,2)^2$ and then (multiplying on the right with an appropriate conjugate) $({}^1_2 {\,}^2_3 {\,}^3_4 {\,}^4_5 {\,}^5_1 {\,}^6_6)$ and then $({}^1_1 {\,}^2_3 {\,}^3_4 {\,}^4_5 {\,}^5_6 {\,}^6_2)$. Finally rotate right once to get $({}^1_2 {\,}^2_1 {\,}^3_3 {\,}^4_4 {\,}^5_5 {\,}^6_6) = (1\,2)$